# Custom Navigation Bar not rectangular

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

Is it possible to customize the Navigation Bar to look like the picture below? Obviously that has a transparent background not a grey one.

[image]

I've tried:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named:"pattern.png"),
                                                            for: .default)
```

That seems to capture the colour but not the format of the navigation bar.

[image]

I am trying to avoid creating a custom nav bar with a UIView or anything like that because that would mean a lot of extra work for such a small change.My app has a lot of views using a Navigation Controller.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this to add the zigzag pattern to your navigationBar (**version2**), or you can create a custom UIImage with your desired pattern  (**version1 (favorite)**)

## Version 1 using UIImage and using self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage method

**Getting the image**

```
import UIKit

extension UIImage {
    
    static func pathZigZagForCGRect(rect: CGRect) ->UIBezierPath
    {
        let width = rect.size.width
        let height = rect.size.height
        
        let zigZagWidth = CGFloat(7)
        let zigZagHeight = CGFloat(5)
        var yInitial = height-zigZagHeight
        
        var zigZagPath = UIBezierPath()
        zigZagPath.move(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:0))
        zigZagPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:yInitial))
        
        var slope = -1
        var x = CGFloat(0)
        var i = 0
        while x < width {
            x = zigZagWidth * CGFloat(i)
            let p = zigZagHeight * CGFloat(slope) - 5
            let y = yInitial + p
            let point = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
            zigZagPath.addLine(to: point)
            slope = slope*(-1)
            i += 1
        }
        
        zigZagPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:width,y: 0))
        zigZagPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:0,y: 0))
        zigZagPath.close()
        return zigZagPath
    }
    

    static func zigZagImage(rect: CGRect,color:UIColor)->UIImage {
        
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0)
        var ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        ctx.clear(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: rect.size.width, height: rect.size.height))
        
        ctx.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
        let path = UIImage.pathZigZagForCGRect(rect: rect)
        ctx.addPath(path.cgPath)
        ctx.fillPath()
        //draw triangle
        
        let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        
        return img
    }
    
}
```

**Using it**

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage( UIImage.zigZagImage(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.width)!, height: (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height)! + 20),color:UIColor.red).resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets.zero, resizingMode: .stretch), for: .default)
    }
```

**Result**

[image]

## Version 2 using layerMask

```
func pathZigZagForView(givenView: UIView) ->UIBezierPath
    {
        let width = givenView.frame.size.width
        let height = givenView.frame.size.height
        
        let zigZagWidth = CGFloat(7)
        let zigZagHeight = CGFloat(5)
        var yInitial = height-zigZagHeight
        
        var zigZagPath = UIBezierPath()
        zigZagPath.move(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:0))
        zigZagPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:yInitial))
        
        var slope = -1
        var x = CGFloat(0)
        var i = 0
        while x < width {
            x = zigZagWidth * CGFloat(i)
            let p = zigZagHeight * CGFloat(slope) - 5
            let y = yInitial + p
            let point = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
            zigZagPath.addLine(to: point)
            slope = slope*(-1)
            i += 1
        }
        
        zigZagPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:width,y: 0))
        zigZagPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:0,y: 0))
        zigZagPath.close()
        return zigZagPath
   }

func applyZigZagEffect(givenView: UIView) {
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer(layer: givenView.layer)
    shapeLayer.path = self.pathZigZagForView(givenView: givenView).cgPath
    shapeLayer.frame = givenView.bounds
    shapeLayer.masksToBounds = true
    givenView.layer.mask = shapeLayer
}
```

**Using it**

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        self.applyZigZagEffect(givenView: (self.navigationController?.navigationBar)!)
    }
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to avoid creating a custom nav bar with a UIView or
>   anything like that because that would mean a lot of extra work for
>   such a small change.My app has a lot of views using a Navigation
>   Controller.

Subclass `UINavigationController` and implement the custom view on the `UINavigationBar` contained within.

Then anywhere you have a navigation controller in the app, replace its class with the custom subclass.

For example:

```
class MyCustomNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // ... code to implement custom view
        // you may not necessarily want to put it in viewDidLoad...
    }

}
```

That way you only have to write the custom view code once. A custom view as your navigation bar is most likely the only way to achieve what you desire.